# Can I run a 32bit Java app on a 64bit platform?

Tags: 64-bit, java, 32-bit

I have an old Java app which has been compiled for the 32bit platform. I've moved from Windows XP (32bit) to OS X Snow Leopard (64bit) and I'd like to continue using this app, however I'm getting an exception along the lines of:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 
/Applications/TheApp/lib/libswt-pi-carbon-3139.jnilib:  no suitable image found.
Did find:
/Applications/TheApp/lib/libswt-pi-carbon-3139.jnilib: mach-o, but wrong 
architecture
```

I've tried using the `-d32` switch when running the app from the command line but with no luck.

**Is it at all possible to run this 32bit app on a 64bit platform without having to recompile** or use a VM?

**Edit:**

I don't have the original source for this application and I'm not overly familiar with developing in Java. If there is a tool I can use to "up-compile"(?) to 64bit that would be useful!

Comment: You might want to install the 32-bit platform as well (I believe you can install both side-by-side, or it might also include the 32 bit JVM).

Comment: if the reason you say you don't wan to recompile it is because you don't have the code, you might be able to decompile it then recompile it.

Comment: @Breakthrough: I believe Snow Leopard has both 32 and 64 builds on it. My `Java Preferences` dialog shows this anyway, and `java -version` returns `"Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.4-b02-402, mixed mode)"`

Comment: Looks like the original program was compiled with some JNI library usage ([Wikipedia JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface)). With pure java you should have no problems.

Answer (score 3):

Java is designed to do this kind of thing transparently. Ever heard the slogan *Compile once, run everywhere*? Well, it's relevant here: *Compile once, debug everywhere*.

The problem you are seeing is because the GUI is windows specific. The [exception you see](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError.html) confirms this. In general, anything that uses SWT or AWT will not work correctly on a different platform unless care is taken to make sure that it does.

Long story short, you're out of luck. You could of course use [JD](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/) to extract the source and modify the GUI code to run properly on OSX. Unfortunately, that would require some experience with Java.